# Switching between html files inside Firefox extension popup?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've been trying to port my Chrome extension over to Firefox. Most of the code worked fine, except for this one thing. The extension popup has [tab buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZMjE.png) at the top which are supposed to switch between different html files (inside the popup) when clicked. However, when the buttons are clicked, the extension simply freezes/crashes.

Here’s an example of the code for the "contact" tab button:

```
 contactTab = document.getElementById("contact-tab")
 
 contactTab.addEventListener("click", function() {
     location = "contact.html"
 })
```

In the Chrome version of my extension I used `location.href` and it worked perfectly fine, this problem is only on Firefox. I’ve tried using `location.href`, `location` and `window.location`, but nothing has worked.

How do I switch between html files in a Firefox extension popup?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `eventListener` in your JavaScript file and do:

```js
window.location.href="yourhtml.html";
```

Path to HTML is based on root directory.